# My suggested edit went into a review queue but now "edit" is greyed out with my suggestion not implemented

Tags: support, suggested-edits

Subject Q: ["parsing the date out of a filename and append it to the beginning"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42585452/parsing-the-date-out-of-a-filename-and-append-it-to-the-beginning)

---

After piecing together the requirements of the user from the original version and various OP comments I did an extensive rewrite, refining requirements, improving the structure used in presenting those, along with adding relevant tags, and I was told by the system after submitting my suggestions that those were queued for peer review pending potential approval.

Now roughly 24 hours later I checked back in and there is no trace left of my edits - considerable effort was put into these, I'd like to mention - nor can I use the "edit" button below this question anymore as it's greyed out.
Inspection of my profile in this matter didn't yield any further information either.

I would expect regardless of the outcome of said peer review process, to be informed of its result in some manner.

*Can anybody provide further clues or explanations of what exactly has happened here?*

I am asking because I hold Stack Overflow and all others in the network in high regard and would very much like to help improve the quality of its content and assist all its users to the best of my abilities in the future. But if my contributions just disappear without any notification or explanation that would seriously impede my motivation for any sort of contribution going forward.

Comment: here is your [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15462416), it is rejected

Comment: Just after submitting my question here I checked back at SO seeing that I received a notification informing me about the rejection of my edit and the reason for the decision. Thank you for your help. How could you review the history of the question's edits. I gladly mark anyone's answer to my question explaining this in more detail as the accepted answer.

Comment: What have confused the reviewers is the fact that the comments are to be found under your answer. This edit is huge I can imagine reviewers decline it despite your effort to make a clear comment

Comment: You can check the [timeline](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42585530/timeline) of a post.

Comment: Where exactly do I find the "Timeline" feature? Sorry for asking for what must be horrendously trivial questions.

Comment: @SvenM. you edit the url of the question replacing questions with posts and adding timeline after the question id. See how I did it by going into edit mode on my answer.

Comment: I am in a bit of an awkward situation here were both answers are very helpful to me but I can only mark one as the approved answer, correct? What now?

Comment: Pick one, or don't pick any, the choice is up to you. There's no rep on meta.

Comment: @RobertLongson Can I go for a second edit of the user's question despite having my first suggestion rejected?

Comment: @SvenM. You can, moderators will eventually step in and can temporarily ban you if you fail to learn but that's mostly to stop people who suggest large numbers of bad edits within a short time period so I wouldn't worry too much about it as long as you [take things slowly till you get the hang of it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91392/too-many-of-your-edits-were-rejected-try-again-in-7-days/92337#92337).

Comment: handy userscript to get the timeline under the posts: http://stackapps.com/questions/2047/add-timeline-and-revisions-links

Comment: @rene cheers! Very helpful indeed.

Comment: @Servy Why did you delete the part where I summarized the solution and what I feel I have gained from that personally in terms of knowledge and experience. Please explain.

Comment: @SvenM. Read the revision notes.  The question is where you ask your question, not where you post your answer.  Of course, that information already exists in the answers already, so there's no reason to re-post it at all.  If it *weren't* already in the answers, then you would post a new answer if you have an answer to the question.

Comment: @Servy Okay that makes sense. I did that in part because I have seen such modes of operation before on SO questions. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: moral of the story is ***do not put effort into fixing other peoples duplicate questions***

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Even you (in the comment you made under the question)

> I have edited your question making clear your requirements among other things assuming as possible inputs for nnn only lower- and uppercase letters. If that does not adhere to your actual requirements please bring those paragraphs in line with your actual requirements.

admit that you've made assumptions here. You [mustn't put words in the mouth of the OP](//stackoverflow.com/help/editing). If he or she wishes to make their question clearer by adding new facts that only they are privy to then all we can do is encourage them to do so. For that we have various tools such as commenting and voting at our disposal.

The reviewers of your edit were [right to reject such a radical change](//stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15462416)

There are various ways to see what happened to a question including the [timeline](//stackoverflow.com/posts/42585452/timeline) which shows the edit review as one of the things happening on the question.

Comment: I chose this answer as the accepted one but the answer from BSMP is equally helpful and should be considered for acquiring a wholesome picture of relevant information in this thread.

Comment: Incredible that you link to the help center implying it says so... when it doesn't. It actually says as common reason to edit a post "To clarify the meaning of the post"! In fact, Shog even said that [such edits are a good form of communication](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288836/792066).

Comment: @Braiam To clarify the meaning is fine, to radically change the post by making assumptions about what the OP actually wanted whether they did or didn't, is not.

Comment: How you can you not change the meaning of the post if the meaning itself is unclear? At the end of the day the OP clarified the meaning, improving the quality of the post. Right now the post is useless, because nobody can guess what the question is about, which wasn't the case with OP edit.

Comment: @Braiam The two relevant bullets I see from that help center link are 1. *To clarify the meaning of the post (**without changing** that meaning)* and 2. *To include **additional information only found in comments**, so all of the information relevant to the post is contained in one place* so it appears to me that the help center is saying precisely what Robert is representing it as saying? Or are there other relevant parts of that page that I'm overlooking?

Comment: @DanBron Robert is saying "You mustn't put words in the mouth of the OP". If the post is unclear (nobody knows what actually means), so editing it "to include additional information only found in comments" that at the same time "clarify the meaning of the post" is a good thing. He's claiming that clarifying the post is putting words in OP mouth, when actually is backwards.

Comment: @Braiam If the edit put information into the post that the OP had already offered up in the comments, I agree it's a fine edit and doesn't put words in OP's mouth. If the edit put words, ideas, or details *not specified by OP* in either the original post or additional comments, then he's putting words in OP's mouth. Because the editor is creating the words/details/ideas, but making it look (by editing) as if OP had said them. As a silly example, if the question was closed because "this can't be answered without knowing what version you're using", it's not ok for an editor to make up "v7.6.2".

Comment: @DanBron and in what way did the editor did that? And even if it did, how can we say he did if we aren't reading said comments?

Comment: @Braiam What do you mean? You can read all the comments on both the question and (as of this writing) the sole answer. None of the assertions in the contested edit make any appearance whatsoever in those comments or the original question. For example, "there is a soft requirement of only using built-in commands". Says who? Where did OP say that? This is how edits are reviewed: the edit is compared to the information provided by the OP, and if there's additional information (guesses) not provided by the OP, then it's putting words in his mouth, and the edit is rejected.

Comment: A quick sniff test is: look at the length (a proxy for "amount of information") in the original post + all comments vs. the length of the proposed edit. Where did all those additional details from from? From the editor's brain, not OP's.

Comment: @DanBron you know that comments can and will be deleted for any reason, right? Editor flags post with text saying "all comments were incorporated into the post, they can be deleted", and poof, bye evidence.

Comment: @DanBron ohoh, look "**I removed all my comments and my answer** in the spirit of harm reduction and the promotion of conciseness", so, there was an answer nobody is seeing, with, guess what, OP comments!

Comment: @Braiam Yes, of course, but then mods can also make invisible edits to posts and could have, for example, changed a super-high-quality question into garbage without anyone knowing. But we don't go around acting like they've done that, it would be irrational an paralyzing. Mods delete noise comments, or obsolete comments, and comments made by OP adding additional details are *not* noise and are *not* obsolete until an editor includes them in the post, which is the very thing we're discussing here. Edit reviewers have to act rationally, i.e. in good faith *on the evidence available to them*.

Comment: @Braiam Yes, that comment was made by *someone who isn't OP*. That is the *point*!

Comment: @DanBron what in the world are you reading? Sven M., the editor and the one asking this meta question, is the one that said the comment, in which he states he had an exchange with the asker of the question, where the post was clarified. What are your complaining about?

Comment: @Braiam He said *he* removed *his* comments, not that OP removed any comments. So far as I can tell, there is no evidence that OP made additional informative comments or that any of OP's comments were removed by anyone.

Comment: @DanBron if he removes the answer where those comments are posted, he removes the comments...

Comment: @Braiam So your take here is that the editor who included all the additional detail in the question got them from comments under an answer which was then deleted? That seems far-fetched to me, but not being 10K on SO I can't even see the timeline of the deleted answer to determine if it's even possible, let alone the actual comments. Nevertheless, based on the information currently available in the entire thread, the reviewers made the correct and rational decision to reject the edit. You can't fault them for not acting on info they didn't have, if that doubtful scenario even happened.

Comment: @DanBron nothing is far fetched, since it's perfectly within the realm of the things allowed by the system. The system allows you to delete your answer, so long as it isn't accepted, which the editor states he did.

Comment: @Braiam That's the difference between "far-fetched" and "impossible". It's also possible, within the rules, that if I buy a lottery ticket, I'll win. It's just far-fetched. Just like this theory you have about what happened on this question.

Comment: I read the question before the comments were deleted. There are no OP comments missing. Several of Sven's have however been deleted, presumably by himself.

Comment: @Braiam ,Robert Longson ,Dan Brown since such a big fuss is made about this I undeleted my answer including my exchange with the OP to which this discussion here relates. I also created a [github gist](https://gist.github.com/Rusk85/d6db941889420906a02ddad4684b56b1) with some more information from the review process. Sadly the actual content of my 2nd suggested edit is lost (see my answer below for at least some details of how and what I changed)after losing my cool when the first reviewer flat out rejected my edit obviously not fact checking my references I made pertaining to OPs requirements

Comment: @RobertLongson "[..]There are no OP comments missing[..]." Sorry that is wrong. I undeleted my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42585530/1352384) which also contains 2 comments of the OP stating his preference for using shell commands and it is strongly implied he is talking about built-in commands though he was open for using my suggested `mmv`tool but wanted to wait for other people to come up with more ideas. He even asked me if he should improve upon his answer or simply write a new. Well you can read it for yourself and draw your own conclusions.

Comment: @SvenM.: Robert is talking about the *question*, where comments you made where indeed deleted.

Comment: @MartijnPieters It is true that I somewhat hastily reacted when I deleted all my comments individually in that question thread except for those which were associated with my answer. Those were deleted automatically along with my answer. Since then I have undeleted my answer and with it my associated comments but also those of the OP. Frankly I don't see what relevance my comments have when the focus here is on determining if in fact the OP provided further details as to the requirements for his posed question in any of his comments. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: @SvenM.: I don't know either, I didn't bother with reviewing the rather sizeable comment thread here (I suggest people take this to chat next time). I'm merely pointing out that Robert is not wrong, as you claimed, when they say comments were deleted *from the question*.

Answer (score 10):

You can find the results of your edit suggestions by going to your profile: Activity> All Actions > [Suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1352384/sven-m?tab=activity&sort=suggestions)

Clicking on the status of an edit takes you to the [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15462416).

The reason given for rejecting your edit was:

> This edit deviates from the original intent of the post. Even edits
>   that must make drastic changes should strive to preserve the goals of
>   the post's owner.

You basically re-wrote the entire question which is in most cases will get the edit rejected. You also added noise to the very end.

Comment: What do mean by "noise"? I am very eager to improve upon my edit skills.

Comment: @SvenM. "Thank you for any advice or pointers in the right direction." is noise. The question is just as answerable (or not) without it.

Comment: Oh I see. That makes sense ofc and is very much my standard etiquette when asking help of others but obviously is inappropriate in that context. Thank you for pointing that out to me. On another note would I be allowed to try another edit of the users' question despite the rejection of my first one?

Comment: @SvenM. Sure, just remember not to put words into people's mouths in future. Everyone has to learn. Reading the help text on editing might help too if you haven't already done so. https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing

Comment: @RobertLongson I must admit to my embarrassment that I haven't. I will now. Thank you.

Comment: @SvenM. you may also read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=fluff+remove to understand background behind "thank you" notes.

Comment: For some more advice on "noise" or waffle see: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/327944/rewriting-a-waffle-question, also see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19564/213772 for no apparent reason except yum.

Answer (score -4):

As I mentioned I would try to edit the user's question a second time and so I went ahead cautiously in slightly rewording the author's question changing the following:

- date -> datetime (his filename included a date and a time)
- made his requirement for having a different format of his datetime type in the output bold (one of the questions actually missed that)
- made his requirement to append the datetime at the beginning bold as well
- added the tag "shell" because he mentioned in one of his comments within that question thread, that he would like to solve his problem using shell commands as he specified OSX as a tag
- also added a reference to the tool mmv I earlier mentioned to him which could potentially achieve his desired goal; in response to my suggestion he specifically mentioned that tool as something he could imagine using to solve his problem
- fixed a typo
- I stated all these things in my edit summary explicitly mentioning the users expressed desire for said solution approaches in his comments

After checking in a couple of hours later the first reviewer flat out rejected all my edits stating this as his reason:

*This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.*

At that point I thought It prudent to rollback all edits to the user's question to its initial original state and also delete all my comments and my answer from the question thread. The rational being that all of my contributions are superfluous and actively harm readability as it was pointed out so accurately by the reviewer. I think providing any sort of contribution to SO is clearly well above my pay grade.

Comment: "added a reference to [x] which could potentially achieve his desired goal" is not really appropriate. Generally, the question should reflect the OP's thinking at the time they asked. This is better in terms of a clear division between Q & A and (usually) in terms of searchability for others who might have similar questions later. Regarding your final paragraph, I think you just had a bad experience because you worked on a poorly posed question with an OP who neglects to improve it. Sticking to good questions is typically more rewarding.

Comment: @Frank Thanks for your input. I completely agree and as you said have moved on. In fact I flagged the question for closing and in the meantime it was put on hold. I consider this a good lesson in SO question editing and the next time around I a few more things to watch out for. That does not mean I have learned all thats to learn in that regard. Quite on the contrary I believe it (read: **I**) will get worse before it gets better and that is fine. I enjoy learning and that inherently involves making mistakes.